# Cert validation failed while connecting from PDO PHP to Postgres using SSL

Tags: php, postgresql, ssl, pdo

I'm trying to connect from PHP PDO to Amazon's PostgreSQL DB instance using SSL. I'm using the following DSN:

```
$db = new PDO('pgsql:host=[host];port=[port];dbname=[db];options=\'--client_encoding=utf8\';sslmode=require;sslcert=/path/domain.crt;sslkey=/path/private.key;sslrootcert=/path/intermediate.ca-bundle;', '[user]', '[pass]');
```

I'm using the same sslcert, sslkey and sslrootcert that are used by Apache on the same client server - they are in PEM format. I can connect using SSL to MySQL with them using following PDO options.

```
$options = [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY           => '/path/private.key',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT          => '/path/domain.crt',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA            => '/path/intermediate.ca-bundle',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => true,
];
```

But for PG, I'm getting:

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] SSL error: certificate verify failed
```

Without SSL, I can connect with no problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: either the file doesn't exist or has permission issue. your web server might not be able to read the file

Comment: @SumitWadhwa Thanks for the comment! But I can connect to MySQL with the same paths. And for PG I already had to add www-data as owner of private key and have only owner be able to read and write it - otherwise there would be error that key file has "group or world access; permissions should be u=rw (0600) or less".

Comment: Look in the server log file to see what the server reported.

Comment: @jjanes Thanks but nothing in error log. Just PDOException is thrown with the above error message. Private key is in PKCS#8 format, and certificate is wildcard. Don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: I've never seen a non-empty connection attempt fail without leaving a message in the database server's log file.  I suspect you aren't looking in the right place.

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to use a client cert?  Only sslrootcert is used by the client for server certs, the rest are just used for client certs.

Comment: @jjanes Sorry for late reply. You are correct, I was looking at the wrong place. The error is:
`[unknown]@[unknown]:[20968]:LOG:  could not accept SSL connection: tlsv1 alert unknown ca`
You are also correct. I didn't need them after all. I just had to specify sslmode and that was it. I was under the impression they are used to identify client domain instead of specific user. Thanks for your help!